# When using System.Diagnostic Process, will I miss some output lines between the start of process and start of capturing output?

Tags: c#, parsing, process, system.diagnostics

If I have code such as

```
proc.Start();
string resultOut;

while ( (!proc.HasExited && (resultOut = stdOut.ReadLine()) != null))
{
// Do some operation based on resultOut
}
```

Am I liable to miss some lines from when I start proc to when the capturing/parsing begins or will it wait? If it doesn't what can I do?

Comment: No, it is buffered.  But missing the *last* line(s) would be a concern.

Comment: I think Hans means you have a bug in your while loop. If stdout is buffered and the process exits, any unread buffered lines may be lost. Simply remove the redundant check for !proc.HasExited. ReadLine returns null only after the stream is closed (by an exiting process) and buffer emptied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're redirecting the input and/or output of the process via [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx), etc, the process output will go directly to your streams.  You won't miss any input or output.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will not lose any lines from stdout.

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "my.exe",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true
};

using (var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo })
{
    process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) =>
    {
        string line = e.Data;            
        //process stderr lines

    };

    process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
    {
        string line = e.Data;
        //process stdout lines
    };

    process.Start();

    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();

    process.WaitForExit();
}
```